404 redirections for valid pages
Our website (Sitecore 10.1.3) is hosted on Sitecore managed cloud. We observed that there are many Failure Requests in Azure App Insights (AAI) and the majority of them are 404 errors.
I have implemented logging to log the "Requested URL" on the incoming request.
Based on the appended query string parameters, I have assumed the original requested page.
The following are the URLs of the 404 page, from AAI and the metric is operation_name = GET /404



Requested URL
Assumed Requested Page (Relative URL)




https://mc-guid-cd.azurewebsites.net/404?item=%2f&layout=%7b00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7d&device=Default
/


https://mc-guid-cd.azurewebsites.net/404?item=%2Fsing&user=extranet%5CAnonymous&site=website
/sing


https://mc-guid-cd.azurewebsites.net/404?item=%2Fwork-and-stay&user=extranet%5CAnonymous&site=website
/work-and-stay


https://example.com/404?item=%2f&layout=%7b00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7d&device=Default
/


https://www.example.com/404?item=%2Fsing&user=extranet%5CAnonymous&site=website
/sing


https://example.com/404?item=%2Fwork-and-stay&user=extranet%5CAnonymous&site=website
/work-and-stay



Some of the URLs captured in logging have the Azure App Service URL and some have the website domain.
All those URLs are valid and will load the respective page when browsed and will not redirect to the 404 page.
Could you please help me understand, what could be the reasons that valid pages are being redirected to 404 page or captured as 404 errors in AAI.
Were they really redirected or there is any other reason for this capturing.
How can I troubleshoot?
Thank you

I believe the operation name is set to /404 as this is the path in all of your examples. Have you checked the resultCode (sometimes called "Request Response code") to see whether you are actually returning a 404 error or not?

@SebastianLay. We have the 404 page item. In AAI, I clicked on Failure Requests > 404 errors and there is huge list and all those pages are "/404". So, I'm assuming the result code is 404, because there are logged under 404 error code.

@sukesh Have you checked the sources of these 404 urls in the AAI? How many requests % are failing like this? I suspect these failing requests to be coming from bots and Sitecore is not serving the right response but instead throws 404.

@ChandraSekaranV 50% are from bots. This is realized from checking the "User-Agent". But the other 50% seems to be from browsers.

If you look at the last processor that gets called in the httpRequestBegin pipeline Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest you will see the HandleItemNotFound(HttpRequestArgs args) method is called if the Context.Item == null
If you look in that function, you will see that is where the item, user and site parameters are added to the query string, before being redirected to the /404 page.
In order to properly understand why these requests are being redirected to the  404 page, you need to work out why the Context Item is null in these situations. Is it possible some process could be calling these pages via an AJAX call or something? (Reason being - I found a post suggesting it would be null in that case).
Alternatively, you might consider adding some additional logging to the Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver processor, which is where the context item is found.
For example, you could check to see if the candidatePath (in function below) contains one of your failing strings (i.e. work-and-stay). Then log if and when it is failing to be resolved (recording variuous params etc).
public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
{
....
foreach (string candidatePath in GetCandidatePaths(args))
{
    if (hashSet.Add(candidatePath))
    {
        if (TryResolveItem(candidatePath, args, out item, out permissionDenied))
        {
            text = candidatePath;
            break;
        }
        if (permissionDenied)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
...
}

Obviously, I would be very wary of doing too much in that processor as it would be called on every request. Ideally, you should be doing it in a test environment. But often these problems dont tend to show up there...
